# NewRelic Service issues on Windows 2012 Server (Standard Edition)

Tags: newrelic

We are running Windows 2012 platform and I recently installed NewRelic client software on 30 different machines (same hardware specifications). I have already installed all relevant .NET framework packages which is required by NewRelic. The installation went well and  machines came up New Relic customer portal but suddenly machines stopped pushing data and one by one I lost all machines.

When I tried to restart new relic service on specific servers and it comes up but again down after sometime. I can't see any error in event logs? I also tried with and without SSL even reinstall NewRelic but it didn't make any difference.

Can anyone suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some clues in the relevant logs.  If you are running version 2 of the Windows Server Monitor, these will be located in the directory C:\ProgramData\New Relic\New Relic Server Monitor\Logs.  If you're running version 3, check for a Custom View in the Windows Event Viewer called "New Relic Windows Server Monitor Events View" - you'll find log messages for the agent there.

What user is running the "nrsvrmon" service?  In most cases, this should be LOCAL\SERVICE.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late reply but some lessons take time to learn.

1. You need to make sure that both the Network Location Awareness and DHCP services are not disabled.
2. In order to get an install log, follow these command line instructions: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/servers/new-relic-servers-windows/installation-configuration/installing-servers-windows#command_install